# Calculate the count from a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i wanna calculate the count of each same services based on user id like the following

2 of type of 5

1 of type of 8

and etc

this screen may help

using laravel  5.3

[image]

Comment: `2 of type of 5` it's a count of rows. If `based on user id` should be 1 because only user_id = 90 get such a service

Comment: you can use group by on 2 column service_id + user_id

Comment: @kerbholz :))) I missed that

Comment: @kerbholz is a pivot that holds all services attached with a reservation , each reservation can have a flight , holiday , other service , at final i will display a report that should tell the admin how much services did the specific user attached to every reservation made

Comment: Oh, ok, based on `user_id=90`, missed the "_based on user id_" part. Nevermind, I'm out ;)

Comment: One other question here is how to attach the user_id dynamically , push it to the table , as you know am using this  $reservation->services()->sync($request->services) ; but this pushes only the reservation_id and service_id how to push the user_id also ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by on multiple table :

**Normal mysql query:**

select serviceid,count(id) as cnt From table Where user_id = 90 group by service_id, user_id

**Laravel :**

```
DB::table("table_name")->select("service_id", DB::raw("COUNT(id) as data_count"))->where('user_id',90)->groupBy("service_id","user_id")->get();
```